# Checking if a word is made up of one or more concatenated dictionary words

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures

Here's the scenario:

I have an array of millions of random strings of letters of length 3-32, and an array of words (the dictionary).

I need to test if a random string can be made up by concatenating 1, 2, or 3 different dictionary words or not.

As the dictionary words would be somewhat fixed, I can do any kind of pre-processing on them.

Ideally, I'd like something that optimizes lookup speeds by doing some kind of pre-processing on the dictionary.

What kind of data structures / algorithms should I be looking at to implement this?

Comment: So it may only be 1, 2 or 3 words (not more)? And it must be the complete random string (not only part of)?

Comment: @MacGucky, I might need to make it support 4 or even 5 words later. Yes, it must be a complete match.

Comment: What are the memory constraints? Why not just create all possible combinations and store in a trie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, Build a <strike>B-Tree like</strike> Trie structure from your dict. Each root would map to a letter. Each 2nd level subtree would then have all of the words that could be made with two letters, and so on.

Then take your word and start with the first letter and walk down the <strike>B-Tree</strike> Trie until you find a match and then recursively apply this algorithm to the rest of the word. If you don't find a match at any point you know you can't form the word via concats.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. I forgot there was a formal name for this structure.

Comment: this fails due to excessive greediness. e.g. if your dictionary contains "FORT", "FORTY" and "TWO", the string "FORTYTWO" would match "FORT", then recursively check "YTWO" and fail.

Comment: and then you would backtrack and find FORTY and then TWO. The search hasn't failed until it proves there are not more matches in a particular sub tree. In this case the FORT subtree has at least two branches to try.

Comment: You don't backtrack, you use a proper DFA.

Comment: What other kind of DFA would you use that would help for this, R?

Answer (score 3):

Store the dictionary strings in a hashed set data structure.  Iterate through all possible splits of the string you want to check in 1, 2 or 3 parts, and for each such split look up all parts in the hash set.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a regex matching every word in your dictionary.
2. Put parentheses around it.
3. Put a `+` on the end.
4. Compile it with any correct (DFA-based) regex engine.